Incorrect Java versions in Visual Studio Code
I am trying to move to visual studio code from my Java work. I have the recommended extensions but I am getting strange errors like:
"The compiler compliance specified is 17 but a JRE 1.8 is used"

I do not have a JDK 17 installed (the project needs to be built with Java 8)

In my root pom.xml I have:
<properties>
    <project.source>1.8</project.source>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>

and in the project .vscode/settings.json:
{
    "java.compile.nullAnalysis.mode": "automatic",
    "java.jdt.ls.vmargs": "-XX:+UseParallelGC -XX:GCTimeRatio=4 -XX:AdaptiveSizePolicyWeight=90 -Dsun.zip.disableMemoryMapping=true -Xmx6G -Xms1G -Xlog:disable",
    "java.configuration.updateBuildConfiguration": "automatic",
    "java.configuration.runtimes": [
        {
            "default": true,
            "name": "JavaSE-1.8",
            "path": "/usr/local/sdkman/candidates/java/current",
        }
    ],
    "java.debug.settings.onBuildFailureProceed": true
}

And to validate this is a Java 8:
~ /usr/local/sdkman/candidates/java/current/bin/java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_292"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (Zulu 8.54.0.21-CA-linux64) (build 1.8.0_292-b10)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (Zulu 8.54.0.21-CA-linux64) (build 25.292-b10, mixed mode)

On the command line the project builds fine. Any idea what can be causing this?

And to validate this is a Java 8: You should probably validate that's global, so cd /tmp then java -version

@g00se Yes I double checked there is no other.
➜  ~ which java
/usr/local/sdkman/candidates/java/current/bin/java
➜  ~ java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_292"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (Zulu 8.54.0.21-CA-linux64) (build 1.8.0_292-b10)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (Zulu 8.54.0.21-CA-linux64) (build 25.292-b10, mixed mode)
➜  ~ echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/local/sdkman/candidates/java/current

Just really feeling around here to see what might be helpful. I've used VSC very little but during that little I've found it to be very unintuitive and possibly just plain buggy. Pity, since afaik it's the only 'IDE' that's not written in Java

By the way, <maven.compiler.source> and <maven.compiler.target> can be replaced with <maven.compiler.release> nowadays.

Also, you should be able to use the latest Java (22 now) while still building for Java 8. You don’t need 8 to build for 8.

this could be the Java plugin in vscode configured to Java17, but you are currently using the JRE version of 1.8. You can choose to install the JDK for Java17 on your computer. You can also use Ctrl+Shift+P in vscode to open the command panel. Input Preferences:Open Settings to open and set "java.configuration.compilerArgs":["-source","1.8","-target","1.8"], and then restart vscode to see if that can solve the problem.

settings.json
"maven.terminal.customEnv": [
  {
    "environmentVariable": "JAVA_HOME",
    "value": "/usr/local/sdkman/candidates/java/current"
  }
]

Note that 'maven.compiler.release' in pom.xml is available only for Java 9 or later.
https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/set-compiler-release.html
Toolchain allows you to specify exactly which JDK version to build.
https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-using-toolchains.html
Specify Project Java Version in VSCode
https://github.com/cypher256/java-extension-pack?tab=readme-ov-file#specify-project-java-version
